# Error "Your yo version is outdated" while setting up our SharePoint Framework development environment

Tags: node.js, powershell, sharepoint, yo, spfx

I am setting up our SharePoint framework development environment inside Windows 7 x64, as mentioned in this video:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

I successfully installed Node.js + VS Code, and now I am at the stage of installing the `yo` package, using this command:

```
npm install -g yo gulp
```

but I got error `"Your yo version is outdated"`, as shown below:

```
V Global configuration file is valid
V NODE_PATH matches the npm root
V Node.js version
V No .bowerrc file in home directory
V No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
× yo version

Your yo version is outdated.

Upgrade to the latest version by running:
npm install -g yo@latest

V npm version

Found potential issues on your machine :(
+ gulp@3.9.1
+ yo@2.0.5
added 787 packages in 229.024s
```

So I ran this command to upgrade `yo`:

```
npm install -g yo@latest
```

but I got the same error:

```
Running sanity checks on your system

V Global configuration file is valid
V NODE_PATH matches the npm root
V Node.js version
V No .bowerrc file in home directory
V No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
× yo version

Your yo version is outdated.

Upgrade to the latest version by running:
npm install -g yo@latest

V npm version

Found potential issues on your machine :(
+ yo@2.0.5
updated 1 package in 38.439s
```

I also tried running these commands:

```
npm rm -g yo
npm install -g yo
```

but they did not fix anything.

And when I wanted to open `yo`, as follows, I got another error:

```
PS C:\Users\*****> yo @microsoft/sharepoint
yo : The term 'yo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ yo @microsoft/sharepoint
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (yo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed same problem on Windows 10/x64, though my installation of nodejs was non-standard "C:\nodejs\".
I fixed up the NODE_PATH to

```
c:\nodejs;c:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules"
```

and PATH to include

```
c:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;
c:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules\.bin;
c:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\;
c:\nodejs;
```

Perhaps the problem was that the yo doctor could not have been able to find itself

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on 3 different PCs, but I now have them all working. As near as I can tell, version 8.x of NodeJS cannot correctly install Yo, but SPFx requires 8 to run. These steps worked for me on all 3 PCs (running Windows 10):

1. install NodeJS version 10.x (currently the LTS version)
2. run these commands from the microsoft tutorial:

   -- `npm install -g yo gulp`

   -- `npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint`
3. At this point, you can create a web part: `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`
4. If you try to run `gulp serve`, it will error, saying you must use a NodeJS version below 9:
   a. Uninstall NodeJS 10.x
   b. Install NodeJS version 8.15
5. If you now run gulp serve, it will again error, but tell you that your environment has changed and give you a command to run. Run the command: `npm rebuild node-sass`
6. (Optional) avoid the certificate error message, run the follow: `gulp trust-dev-cert`

You should now be able to run gulp serve on your SPFx web parts using the correct versions of Node and Yo.

I really want to throw a "... and Bob's your uncle!" reference for the 100 in here.